# How do I absolutely position a relatively positioned element?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a container, and that I want to put this one container into yet *another* container that's also full of other stuff. The CSS code might look something like this:

```css
.parent-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.child-container {
    width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

However, `.child-container` also includes absolutely positioned elements, which are position relatively to `.parent-container` because `.child-container` doesn't have `position: relative`. So my question is, how can I position `.child-container`'s children relatively to itself, while still keeping it correctly positioned in `.parent-container`?

P. S. Wrapping `.child-container` in a `position: absolute`'d `div` and making `.child-container` `position: relative` should do the trick, but I was hoping for something more... semantic.

Comment: The children of `.child-container` position according to `.child-container`, not `.parent-container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements should *already* be relative to their parent. Here's a demo which shows nested items within absolute positioning

**HTML**

```html
<div class='parent-container'>
    Parent
    <div class='child-container'>
        1st Child
        <div class='grandchild-container'>
            2nd Child
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (*color added to illustrate differences*)

```css
.parent-container {
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
}
.child-container {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    left: 20px;
}
.grandchild-container {
    position: absolute;
    background: yellow;
    left: 20px;
}
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycSW7/1/)

It will look like this

[image: demo] *Notice each position is relative to its parent.

For more info see:

- [Positioning - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
- [Position - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 4):

> However, .child-container also includes absolutely positioned elements, which are position relatively to .parent-container because .child-container doesn't have position: relative.

Incorrect. Absolute positioning is with respect to the nearest ancestor that is *positioned*, not `position: relative`. Anything except `position: static` will make an element positioned. (`position: relative` won't move the container out of normal flow so it is used when you want to set a positioning context with no side effects).

Since the parent is `position: absolute;` they are positioned with respect to that already.

Comment: Oh, great! This applies to HTML5 as well, yes?

Comment: Browsers don't distinguish between versions of HTML, and this is part of the CSS specification not the HTML specification anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change .child-container position to relative in order to set him has "relative" parent. 
please review this link from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) about position absolute.

"The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used."

*positioned ancestor is an element with either: relative, fixed or **absolute** position